# SFTP is working but SSH failed why?

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, sftp

I have SFTP client library[3rd party] which Fails to connect to the sftp server [use password authentication].

From 3rd party log file  I can see that SSH/SFTP authentication is successs but ssh channel open is failed hence sftp connect is failing....

3rd party library first creates ssh tunnel and then cretaes a channel and then open a sftp-subsystem

I can see that ssh tunnel is create successfuly , but channel open is
failed [server send the channel open failure msg], this may be becuase the user doesn't have ssh access to that server . But I am not sure

I can do manual sftp using command but  SSH failed.
sftp  syeds@10.18.20.13   works
ssh   syeds@10.18.20.13   Fails

OS: Linux

But why manuly sftp command working fine ?

Comment: Perhaps the remote account has shells disabled?

Comment: Maybe the remote server is using SSH1 that does not have support for subsystems. In what way connecting to the remote server via SSH fails? and BTW, which library are you using?

Comment: You can use `-vvv` parameter for ssh log output (the more `v` the more verbose ...) to get more detailed information where the connection fails.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be having two different problems:

- impossibility to login to shell (shell access can be disabled on the server) and
- impossibility for the library to open SFTP connection.

In the latter case you need to contact library vendor for assistance - there can be different reasons for the problem.

One thing you can do yourself is check that SFTP subsystem is really configured on the server. If SFTP server is not specified in config, some applications manage to open command channel and try to guess SFTP server location and run it via command channel. Libraries usually don't do this.